# Showing Complete Set of Data with Filter and parameter - Tableau 10

Tags: filter, parameters, tableau-api

I have a set of data below.

```
| AdviserName | PolicyNumber | Product | Status | Duration |
|-------------|--------------|---------|--------|----------|
| Andy        | LIF123       | ANZ     | New    | 2        |
| Andy        | X224         | AXA     | Lapsed | 3        |
| George      | KL1122       | TAL     | New    | 0        |
| George      | OLK43        | AXA     | Lapsed | 5        |
| Ben         | LIF98        | ANZ     | New    | 0        |
| Ben         | KL343        | TAL     | Lapsed | 1        |
```

I want to get the set of data where the status = 'Lapsed' duration between 1 to 3. However I still want to show correspond status = 'New' for each adviser. Below is the expected result that I want to see.

```
| AdviserName | PolicyNumber | Product | Status | Duration |
|-------------|--------------|---------|--------|----------|
| Andy        | LIF123       | ANZ     | New    | 2        |
| Andy        | X224         | AXA     | Lapsed | 3        |
| Ben         | LIF98        | ANZ     | New    | 0        |
| Ben         | KL343        | TAL     | Lapsed | 1        |
```

I created 2 parameters :

- `MinYear` with the value set to 1
- `MaxYear` with the value set to 3

I created 2 calculated fields :

- `MinInvYear` which is `iif([Duration]>=[Min Year] and [Status] = 'Lapsed', 1, 0)`
- `MaxInvYear` which is `iif([Duration]<=[Max Year] and [Status] = 'Lapsed', 1, 0)`

Last step, I put both calculated fields into the filters and tick the filter = 1 only. Unfortunately what I got is the table below. I need to show the status 'New' as well for Andy and Ben.

```
| AdviserName | PolicyNumber | Product | Status | Duration |
|-------------|--------------|---------|--------|----------|
| Andy        | X224         | AXA     | Lapsed | 3        |
| Ben         | KL343        | TAL     | Lapsed | 1        |
```

I tried to modify the calculated field using Level of Detail :

`MinInvYear` which is `{include [Status] = 'New Business' : iif([Duration]>=[Min Year] and [Status] = 'Lapsed', 1, 0)}` and I got error message 'Result of a level of detail expression must be aggregate.'

What am I missing?

FYI, I'm using Tableau 10.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the 2 calculated fields `MinInvYear` and `MaxInvYear`, try adding a calculated field (let's say `Filter for Status and Duration`) which returns a boolean value based on your condition

```
IF ([Status] == 'Lapsed' OR ([MinYear] < [Duration] AND [Duration] < [MaxYear])) THEN
    TRUE
ELSE
    FALSE
END
```

Now, add a filter for this calculated field to show only records which result in `True`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, Bit lengthy but works for sure:

You are manipulating on only one aspect (Lapsed) of the field status, hence you are applying the parameter values on only that value. So here you need to independently work on that column to get the required output. Follow the below process:

1. Create 2 sets for each value in status column:

Set 1: `Lapsed`

```
Here create a set and just select checkbox `Lapsed`.
```

Set 2: `New`

```
Here create a set and just select checkbox `New`.
```

2. Create two calculated fields to extract the required data separately for `Lapsed` and `New`

Calculated Field 1: `Lapsed_Status`

```
IF [Duration] >= [Min] and [Duration] <= [Max]
THEN [Lapsed] //Set
END
```

Calculated Field 2: `New Status`

```
IF [New]=[New]
THEN [New] //Set
END
```

3. Create two more sets out of 2 calculated fields (created in step 2) to just select only those values that are needed for display on sheet:

Set 3: `Display_Lapsed` //From Calculated Field 1: `New Status`

```
Select checkbox True
```

Set 4: `Display_New` //From Calculated Field 2: `Lapsed_Status`

```
Select checkbox True
```

4. Now we have our required data in 2 sets, Create one more calculated field and use in filter

Calculated Field 'Display_sheet'

```
Display_Lapsed <> Display_New //Both are sets
```

5. Use the calculated field `Display_sheet` in filter and select `true`
6. Use the required fields on the sheet to display data.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks for your help. Step 2 I got error message, 'Cannot use 'Boolean' type in 'if' expression.

Comment: Actually I have implemented at my side with the data you provided and I got no error message. Can you post the formula that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Below trick will get you moving

- Duplicate the data source (right click on the data source in 'Data' panel -> 'Duplicate') having above data
- Drag `AdviserName` from the original data source in 'Rows' view
- Click on the duplicated data source in 'Data' panel. There you'll find 'link symbol' next to every dimension (in grey color). Click on the 'link symbol' next to `AdviserName` and it'll turn 'red' (if it turns grey don't worry. Click again and it'll turn red). Be sure that only one 'link symbol' is red (which is next to `AdviserName`).
- Create a calculated field `filter_cond` in this duplicated data source as

---

```
IF [Status]='Lapsed' and [Duration]<=3 and [Duration]>=1
then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END
```

- Drag `filter_cond` in 'Filters' view and select 'Y'
- Now drag `PolicyNumber`, `Product` & `Status` from the original datasource in 'Rows' view. You are done!

Voila!

Comment: @AdhityaSanusi - Is the suggested solution of any help? Pls don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)